# Solution for inequality: $ \frac{\log p}{e^{wp}} \leq z^2 $

Tags: inequality

I am currently looking at some concentration bounds (Law of iterated logarithm) and trying to find the number of samples/steps required so that the deviation from mean is within some small $\epsilon$.

But that is not my problem (just trying to give context for the problem here). I have simplified it to the following form:

$ \frac{\log p}{e^{wp}} \leq z^2 $.

I want to find an inequality of the form:$ p \geq f(w,z) $.

$w, z$ are small ($ < 1$) constants. Any ideas on how I can proceed here?

Comment: How large do you expect p to be?

Comment: For the problem at hand, p can be any arbitrarily large real (> 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of approaching the problem. For ease of representation and to bring out the idea more clearly, I will solve for following inequality:

$\frac{p}{e^{wp}} \leq z$

By simple rearrangement,
\begin{equation}
p \geq \frac{1}{w} \cdot \log\left( \frac{p}{z} \right)
\end{equation}

Using the lower bound: $ 1 - \frac{1}{x} \leq \log x$

\begin{equation}
p + \frac{z}{wp} \geq \frac{1}{w}
\end{equation}

At this stage, I simply make an observation that the inequality must be true for $p \geq \frac{1}{w}$. Using this lower bound in above equation:
\begin{equation}
p \geq \frac{1}{w} \cdot \log\left( \frac{1}{wz} \right)
\end{equation}

One can use the same idea for the problem I posed. One observation I made here is that the final bound obtained is heavily dependent on the quality of lower bound one can give for $ \log p$ here. In my opinion, the lower bound for log x used is rather poor. But I don't know of any better bound.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the log of both sides gives:

$$\log(\frac{\log p}{e^{wp}})\leq \log z^2-------(1)$$

As you know, $\log(\frac{a}{b})=\log a-\log b$. Also, $\log e^{x}=x$. Hence, (1) becomes:

$$\log \log p -wp \leq \log z^2.$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: Your reputation number looks a bit hexakosioihexekontahexaphobic :)

Comment: Hahahaha...666.
Perhaps, it will be changed soon.

Comment: It think I better do it now)

Comment: Is it supposed to be trivial from here?

Answer (score 1):

Just a try...

The part
$$
\frac{ \log(p) }{ \exp(wp)}
$$

has a zero at $p=1$, so we write

$$
\log(1 + \epsilon) \exp( -w )^{1 + \epsilon} \approx \epsilon \exp(-w) 
$$

So an approximation would be
$$
\epsilon \le z^2 \exp(w).
$$

As $p = 1 + \epsilon$, we get
$$
p \le 1 + z^2 \exp(w),
$$

but only as an approximation...

Comment: Thanks for your try! Two problems though: 1. This won't work for larger values of p 2. Because of the way the approximation is done, direction of inequality is not clear.